# Add bash script folder to path?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have some bash scripts in an application folder that I'd like to use as if they were on my path.  If they were straight-up applications, I'd just add the directory to ~/.bashrc, but these are scripts.

eg:

```
~/a_dir/another_dir/foo.sh
~/a_dir/another_dir/foo-gui.sh
```

Is there a good way to set up a path so that I can use them from any directory?

eg:

```
totally/different/path$ bash foo.sh
```

Comment: you won't be able to do it with ``bash foo.sh``, but with ``foo.sh``, after giving exec permission and putting them in the $PATH.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can add any directory to the system path. One way to do this is updating the PATH (environmental variable) definition. You can do this in your `.bashrc` by adding the following lines:

```
PATH="/your/script/dir:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I like to add my scripts to `$HOME/.local/bin/` (which is a hidden directory) so my home dir stays cleaner.

Your directory will not get inserted into the PATH variable right away, unless you run `source .bashrc`.

You can add multiple directories to the path, remember that. Please consult BASH documentation if you do not understand the code.

The previous method will only work for your user. If you need to add a script directory for all users do as *bodhi.zazen* and add your scripts to `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Adding it before overrides the system scripts - meaning it could be easy to replace em which ain't always good.

Comment: Yeah, the potential of a process dropping say a script called less into your ~/.local/bin directory means a process could override your less command to do their own thing using your permissions and then pass the command to less. Silently usurping your authority on the system. True, other things have to break at that point, but someone could get tricked into that.

Answer (score 10):

IMO the best method is to add the scripts to ~/bin

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

`~/bin` should automatically be added to your path. If not, add this to `~/.bashrc`

```
if [ -d $HOME/bin ]; then
    PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
fi
```

If you want them to be available for all users, add them to `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: In this case, since it's scripts from an applications, I'd advise to put symbolic links for the scripts in the ``~/bin``, for better maintainability.

Answer (score 5):

another solution

1. Add path to `~/.bashrc` open using vim `$ vim ~/.bashrc`

   example:

   `# add extra paths
   export PATH=$PATH:~/Scripts`
2. once path is added run:

   `$ source ~/.bashrc`
3. If added correctly there should be no errors.