# Add custom script to PATH

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

I know there are quite some answers about that, but still could not make my way around it. I read [all this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) and tried to follow the example under **System-wide environment variables** (for my case of course), and also tried to do as the chosen answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97897/add-bash-script-folder-to-path). But didn't work.

**So, I have an executable shell script, located in `~/Developer/android-studio/bin` and I want to make it so that when I am in the terminal (no matter were) and I write simply `android-studio` and the script to be executed (the IDE to start).**

So, I tried with `export AS=$PATH:~/Developer/android-studio/bin` and also with

```
AS="~/Developer/android-studio/bin:${PATH}"
export AS
```

and then `source .bashrc`, but after both tries, when I write simply `AS` I get `command not found`. How can I make this work?

Another question - is it obligatory that I name the variable with capitals only and no dashes, because I want to name the variable something like `android_studio` instead of `AS`, i.e.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/Developer/android-studio/bin"
```

Then you'll be able to enter `android-studio` from anywhere. There's nothing magical about an environment variable named `AS`

If you want a shorthand, add a function to your .bashrc:

```
function as() { command android-studio "$@"; }
```

Comment: Ok, let me understand this completely... With the first line `PATH=...` I add my directory to the $PATH env. variable, right? And then how would I denote `android_studio` to correspond to the added directory? (if we exclude the last line that you wrote with the function).

Comment: Once the directory is in the PATH, bash will be able to find the program "android_studio" in exactly the same way it can find the program "ls": by searching the directories in the PATH variable.