# How to add a python script as a terminal command?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, scripts, execute-command

Lets say I have a script which creates a file and writes something into it (but could be anything). It could be a script that runs a set of `xrandr` commands to set a resolution, for example.

Is there a way in which I can create a command (working *only* on my system) that executes the file, even if the file is not in my working directory?

Comment: Just speculation, but couldn't you add its parent directory to your $PATH? That would let you run it by typing just its name, wouldn't it?

Comment: You can do something like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84690)

Comment: For stuff that's specific to me, I put it in my ~/bin directory, and that directory is in my $PATH

Comment: You could chuck it into a folder that appears in `echo $PATH` - or you can [add a folder to the the path](http://askubuntu.com/a/97898/178596) (note may not work with sudo). There must be atleast 50 questions already like this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu, the default `.profile` adds your `$HOME/bin` directory to `$PATH`, assuming the former exists. This means that you can create a `bin` directory in your home, and any executables in there can be run without specifying the full path, which is what you want.

In the case of a Python script, also make sure that it's executable (`chmod u+x blahblah`) and it has the proper shebang on the first line, usually:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Additionally, after creating the `~/bin` directory, you need to either close and reopen your terminal window or run `source ~/.profile` again. Otherwise the PATH will not be updated yet.