# How to place software files

Tags: software-installation, directory, tor

I've installed Tor, and now I'd like to install the Tor Browser. I'm following the instructions under [Linux Instructions](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux).

The package `tor-browser-linux64-5.5.4_en-US.tar.xz` has been downloaded and unpacked to my `~/Downloads/` directory. I can easily launch the browser from there.

However, I want to place the files in the correct locations, but I don't know where. As I understand it support files are supposed to go in one directory, lib files in another, executables in another, etc.

Is there a console command I can use to automatically distribute all the Tor Browser files from `~/Downloads/` to the correct locations?

I'm very new to Ubuntu and have never installed anything this way before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a console command I can use to automatically distribute all the Tor Browser files from ~/Downloads/ to the correct locations?

No, you got that wrong.

- "debian" installer files will install software into the Ubuntu directories. See Ubuntu software center for an easier way to installing this:

[image]

- But you used a 3rd party method (.tar.gz) and 3rd party software should use "/opt/". The Linux way to do this is to do a ...

  ```
  cd ~/Downloads
  sudo mv tor-browser* /opt/
  sudo chown $USER:$USER tor-browser*
  ```

And then add the directory to your $PATH. A howto on how to do that: [Add bash script folder to path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97897/add-bash-script-folder-to-path?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? https://i.sli.mg/QtXPZI.png

Comment: If I include "cd ~Downloads/" at the beginning of the command it only creates an empty folder called "opt" inside ~/Downloads/tor-browser_en-US

Comment: You need to move the "unpacked" data to /opt/. Oh and those are 3 commands.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a step closer now. What's the purpose of adding the directory to my path?

Comment: That way you can use command line to start the browser from anywhere. You can also create a launcher though and use that.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind, makes sense. Consider the issue solved.